# Perl/tk, Grid and resizing

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have simple Perl/Tk application. I use "grid" to place widgets on mainwindow. But the problem is that widgets' size doesn't change when I resize my mainwindow. There is just a blank place and all widgets with old size. How can I autoresize widgets?

Comment: Say, have you tried to search for solutions yourself? A simple query for `Tk resize` already yields useful results (you just have to translate the solution to the Perl bindings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `-sticky` option, i.e.

```
$mw->SomeWidget(...)->grid(..., -sticky => 'nsew');
```